# How to store utf8 to mysql 5.X via jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, utf-8

I am trying to store data to mysql, an excerpt of which is shown here:

```
"description":"★배달 사고 혹은 장난주문 방지주 찾는 배달음식점 즐겨찾기\n지난 주문 내역 확인\n포인트 적립 및 결제\n소셜 네트워크 연동을 통한 평가 남기기\n철가방에서 제공하는 다양한 이벤트", "currency":"USD", "genres":["Food & Drink", "Lifestyle"], "genreIds":["6023", "6012"], "releaseDate":"2011-10-10T07:00:00Z", "sellerName":"sang yoon woo", "bundleId":"kr.co.helloworld.hellodelive/us/app/cheolgabang/id468583150?mt=8&uo=4", "trackContentRating":"4+", "averageUserRating":5.0, "userRatingCount":2},
```

{"kind":"software", "features":["iosUniversal"], "supportedDevices":["all"], "

It appears to be utf8. I have tried to set utf8 in all the appropriate places but have been unsuccessful to save to mysql.

The following behavior is observed both on 5.1 and 5.5 mysql databases via jdbc using connector/J.

Here are the things I have tried:
(a) just use defaults. does not work, the ascii chars are fine but not the CJK ones.

(b) Set utf8 everywhere: in the connection, in the table, in the connection and client again..  No change /not succesful to store utf8 characters properly (they are shown as ? etc).  To answer jim's question: The data is checked directly on the mysql server using mysql prompt with character encoding of utf8.

```
  DB.execute(conn, "SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'",false);
  DB.execute(conn,"drop table if exists dummy1; ",false);
  DB.execute(conn,"create table dummy1 (id int auto_increment primary key, contents blob) default charset='latin1';",false);
String insert = String.format("insert into dummy1 (contents) values ('%s');", escapedContents);
    DB.DBResult result = DB.execute(conn, insert, true);
```

Then I tried to add connection parameters as follows:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/classint?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
```

but the following error occurs:

```
useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8" as stephenb: Unsupported character encoding 'utf8"'.
```

(Edit note:  this error of unsupported encoding turned out due to a hanging double quote on the end of the jdbc url: after removing it - as seen in current version above, this particular error disappears. but the overall problem of multi-byte characters getting garbled in the database remains)

Here is an excerpt of the mangled output, which should have had korean characters:

```
     "price":0.00, "version":"2.1.1", "description":"âë°°ë¬ ì¬ê³  í¹ì ì¥ëì£¼ë¬¸ ë°©ì§ë¥¼ ìí´ í´ëí°ì¸ì¦ì ì¤ìí©ëë¤
```

Further, I would mention that the data is verified as correct because the same data is written to amazon s3 and it is correct (korean characters are whole there).

Comment: _"unsuccessful to save to mysql."_ -- in what way? How do you _know_ you are unsuccessful?  For starters, use `PreparedStatement` and placeholders instead of building the insert statement dynamically, which is just asking for SQL injection, and won't work if the data to be inserted contains a quote character anyway.

Comment: I had already tried PreparedStatement and placeholders. However, I will clarirfy the "unsuccessful" aspect.  AFA sql injection I am well aware of that, this code is an internal firewalled application with no gui or external access.

Comment: Why do you have `default charset='latin1'` in there?

Comment: good eyes, I will correct that in this question. In real life, i have tried every combination: apparently the last one attempted was with latin1. I have reverted this to utf8 and still same (wrong results). I added the (bad) results to the OP

Comment: Don't try combinations, that's how many encoding problems start in the first place. When you always use the same encoding in every possible place, there is no encoding mismatch possible which garbles characters like this. Anyway, have you verified that the data is correct before you even send it to the database? Note that verifying is sensitive to encoding as well because to see output you need to specify an output encoding. You should use `.equals` with  equal string using `\u` escapes for the non-ASCII characters so you know that verification is not affected by encoding at all.

Comment: The data is verified as correct by writing it to flat file locally just before writing to the database. In the flat file, the korean characters show up properly (viewable in text editor).         AmFileUtils.write("/shared/escaped.txt", escapedContents);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store utf8 to mysql you should define your table column as utf8 character set and also create connection with UTF-8 characterEncoding. as you see here:

```
        //Load jdbc driver
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        //Open a connection to server   
        Connection conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?characterEncoding=UTF-8", USERNAME, PASSWORD);

        //Create statement for query
        Statement stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();  

        //create table column with character set utf 8
        stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE table1 (id int,name varchar(20) character set utf8);");

        //INSERT query
        stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO table1 (id,name) VALUES ('12','汉语')");

        //SELECT query
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM table1");
        System.out.println(rs.getString("name"));
```

Comment: Hi Ahmad,  I do not have access to the testing code I was working with at this time.  Please  create and run a test program that ingests CJK data from mysql and you can read it back from mysql. Then post the info / results here. I will then award the correct answer.

Comment: Answer edited with an example, don't forget to mark answer as correct ;)